# can we use group by in this manner?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df having more than 100 columns and i want to use groupby and take mean of column having 'WR' in it and 'sum' if not using agg().

```
df.groupby([c1,c2]).agg({ {i for i in df.columns if 'WR' in i}:'mean', {i for i in df.columns if 'WR' 
not in i}:'sum'})
```

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionaries by `dict.fromkeys` and [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) them together:

```
d1 = dict.fromkeys([i for i in df.columns if 'WR' in i], 'mean')
d2 = dict.fromkeys([i for i in df.columns if 'WR' not in i], 'sum')

df.groupby([c1,c2]).agg({**d1, **d2})
```

Another similar solution:

```
m = df.columns.str.contains('WR')

d1 = dict.fromkeys(df.columns[m], 'mean')
d2 = dict.fromkeys(df.columns[~m], 'sum')

df.groupby([c1,c2]).agg({**d1, **d2})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
```

d1= dict.fromkeys([i for i in df.columns if 'WR in i],'mean')
    d2=dict.fromkeys([i for i in df.columns if'WR' not in i],'sum')
    df.groupby([c1,c2]),agg({**d1,**d2})